# Compare two chinese words to be equal

Tags: python

I want to compare two chinese words as below (they should be same):

```
d = "进 出口中心"
s = "进出口中心"

print(d == s)
```

They seem to be equal, but not returned equal. When I put these code in to `IDLE (Python GUI)` it looks like:

```
>>> d = "进�出口中心"
>>> s = "进出口中心"
>>> print(d == s)
```

There's a special character `�` in the word.

How can I remove this character or other special character like it, and make these two words equal?

Thanks!

Comment: I pasted your first snippet in my IDLE and it also printed `False`, however when copying the value of `d` to the value of `s` it prints `True`. I didn't have a special character issue (Windows EN-US)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to [Unicode control characters](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode%E6%8E%A7%E5%88%B6%E5%AD%97%E7%AC%A6)

```
U+2028 line separator ，HTML：&#8232;，LSEP

U+2029 paragraph separator ，HTML：&#8233;，PSEP
```

So replace these unicode separator works

```
d = "进 出口中心"
s = "进出口中心"

d = d.replace(chr(8232), "")\
     .replace(chr(8233), "")

print(d == s) # True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove non-printable characters from the strings by testing the characters with the `str.isprintable` method before a comparison is made:

```
def remove_nonprintable(s):
    return ''.join(c for c in s if c.isprintable())

assert remove_nonprintable(d) == remove_nonprintable(s)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately there would be some `- ( ,` in word

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer with a different approach then.

Comment: That's good. Can you explain why this special character appeared in  `d`?

Comment: No one knows where and how you obtain `d` if you don't tell us. It's also out of the scope of this question. Please ask a different question with the code that produces the content of `d` so we can help see how the special character gets introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Well one approach here would be to strip off the special separator character(s) first, and then do the comparison:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

d = "进 出口中心"
s = "进出口中心"

d = re.sub(r'[ ]', '', d)  # add more characters to the class as necessary
print(d)       # 进出口中心
print(d == s)  # True
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what character it will be. And I really don't know why they looking alike `d = "进 出口中心"
s = "进出口中心"`